# Return string for category based on max value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm attempting to return the color for which the vehicle had the highest sales. My [sales] table looks like so:

| Vehicle | Color | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | Blue | 5 |
| Car | Red | 8 |
| Truck | Silver | 10 |
| Truck | Orange | 4 |

I created a table listing the vehicle as a column and now I need my dax measure to return the following:

| Vehicle | Most Sold |
| --- | --- |
| Car | Red |
| Truck | Silver |

I've tried a couple of different approaches and ideally wanted to use LOOKUPVALUE but I can't use max expression like so:

```
Most Sold = 

RETURN LOOKUPVALUE(Sales[Color], Sales[Sold], MAX(Sales[Sold])
```

What would be the best approach here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

Here you go.

```
Most Sold = MAXX(TOPN(1, Sales, Sales[Sold]), Sales[Color])
```

[image]

Comment: The most sold isn't always the first choice though. My apologies for not making that clear.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Isn't the requirement "I'm attempting to return the color for which the vehicle had the highest sales"? This measure does that. What is the actual requirement?

Comment: The TopN works only if the first occurrence contains the highest sales. If let's say Red Car was the second occurence instead of the first it would return blue car and not red car.

Comment: Have you tried the code as I'm still not following. Can you add more sample data and expected results.

Comment: Ok I've revised my initial post and all I did was switch the order of blue to be on top and red to be on bottom. When I try TopN it no longer returns red as the most sold

Comment: My bad - I missed the order by expression. I'll update now.

Comment: Thank you so much for following up. I appreciate you!